# How to create a dropdown menu in the top navbar with bootstrap 3.3.7?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a project that is using Bootstrap [3.3.7](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar). I need to add a dropdown menu in the navbar.

I thought I got the right markup in place. However, the dropdown menu is not showing up as expected

Here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top sticky-top" >
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
         Business Name
         </a>
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown notification-container">
               <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Notifications
               <span class="notification-count badge">3</span>
               </a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-backdrop" style="width: 240px;">
                  <li class="p-2 border-bottom notification-message message-unread">
                     <a href="#"><small>Message 1</small></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="p-2 border-bottom notification-message message-unread">
                     <a href="#"><small>Message 2</small></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="p-2 border-bottom notification-message message-unread">
                     <a href="#"><small>Message 3</small></a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <div class="navbar-text mr-3 ml-1" style="margin-right: 12px; margin-left: 4px; "> Hello, Jake!</div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
   </div>
</nav>
```

I also created a fiddler with the code to show how the notification menu on the upper right-hand side is not showing the items when it is clicked https://jsfiddle.net/tsjLhvz2/

How can I get the menu in the navbar to open up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the .dropdown-backdrop, for some reason that class is triggering your list to be removed from the DOM.

Comment: The following fiddler shows the code with Jquery https://jsfiddle.net/vownpyq2/1/ yet it is still now working

Comment: remove this class '.dropdown-backdrop' from the ul element.